# How do I use already existing unique identifies in Airtable?

Tags: airtable

I have an Air-table base with the following information:

```
Company     ID

  A         123
  B         456
  C         789
```

My question is how do I make the ID field into the record ID? Because, the issue I am having right now is that Air-table is automatically putting a `Record ID` field for a unique Identifier. I want the unique identifier to be my already existing ID field. But, I have not been able to get the functionality I want without completely overwriting the ID field. Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking in the context of the Airtable Scripting environment? Or just in general, base design-wise? When you say Airtable is "putting" (using?) those ids as identifiers, what exactly do you mean?

The randomly generated record ids can't be 'replaced' but aren't exactly forced upon you, either. And while you can avoid relying on them without much hassle  in favor of your own machinations, doing so is all but guaranteed to be a waste of your time - why reinvent the wheel? So, I'd appreciate more info on your situation, but it's even more important you reassess whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

map it

```
let recs=new Map(query.records.map(r=>[r.getCellValue('ID'),r.id]))
```

(or, getCellValueAsString..)

thus, `recs.get('123')` returns record id (string like 'rec3Hj343cddk')

`rec.has('456')` - boolean to check existing or filter

if it doesn't fit your needs, then Dominik is right - you need to rethink your goal.